# Azure pipeline: exclusive lock sequential not locking jobs from other runs

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a Pipeline like:

```
lockBehavior: sequential
stages:
  ...
```

Inside the pipeline I have in the same stage jobs executed in the same computer, let's say *job1->computer1 job2->computer1*.
If After a first run, let's say *run1*, I ran the pipeline again *run2* before that *run1->job1* is finish, then *run2->job1* is executed before *run1->job2*.

Is this a bug or am I missing something in the exclusive lock behaviour? Do I need to specify an environment instead of the computer directly?
Thanks a lot in advance.

I was expecting the lock to change the behaviour but the result is identical to not having a lock. The result is also the same if I place the lock inside the stage with the jobs.

Comment: Hi,Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

To use exclusive lock check with sequential deployments or runLatest, follow these steps:

1. Enable the exclusive lock check on the environment (or another protected resource).
2. In the YAML file for the pipeline, specify a new property called lockBehavior. This can be specified for the whole pipeline or for a given stage.

Please refer to doc: [Support for sequential deployments when using exclusive lock checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-190-update#support-for-sequential-deployments-rather-than-latest-only-when-using-exclusive-lock-checks)

Checks are used to control the execution of stages on protected resources: [Protected resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/resources?view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true#protected-resources)

Please enable this with the target protected resource first.

Agent pool example:
[image: add Agent pool check]

Variable group example:
[image: add Variable group check]

I test my pipeline with protected resource: variable group and it works. The run2 didn’t execute until run1 finished and released protected resource.
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The photos helped a lot.
I was also very confused by this behaviour pointed in:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/yaml-pipeline-exclusive-lock-should-not-unlock-in/1513835 ->that this does not work for jobs in different stages. I hope that they fix it soon. Have a great day!

Comment: @C.JavierGonzálezChamorro  When you put the jobs in separate stages, the exclusive lock of the environment will be judged separately. It is not able to apply the exclusive lock at the pipeline level. To meet your requirement, you can define required the jobs in the same stage. Or wait for this feature to be published.